# Ag-grid hide tool panel collapsed

Tags: ag-grid

I want to start the grid in mode collapsed
the panel right collapsed how do that? 
I´m used Enterprise version: v21.0.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACq51.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gridApi method closeToolPanel() to close it:

```
gridApi.closeToolPanel();
```

There are few other methods that might be useful to you: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#side-bar-api